# How to add values from multiple MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm trying to add the count of items from multiple mysql databases  (I haven't got to the adding part yet) to print the total number of records on my homepage.

I've grab the 'count' code basics from a couple sites I Googled, but something is not quite right. If I run the query below by itself in phpMyAdmin, it works fine (I get 36 results from this 1 database), but when I run it in my php page, via the below code, it only returns a count of 1.

Any idea what I'm messing up?  Thanks.

```
$connection="localhost";
$username="myusername";
$password="mypassword";
$database1="mydb1";
$database2="mydb2";

$db1 = mysql_connect($connection,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
$sel1 = mysql_select_db($database1, $db1);
$query1 = "SELECT count(postID) FROM my_table";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1, $db1);

$db2 = mysql_connect($connection,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
$sel2 = mysql_select_db($database2, $db2);
$query2 = "SELECT count(postID) FROM my_table";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $db2) or die(mysql_error());

$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);
print $total_rows;
```

Comment: why are you creating multiple instances of your connection? You can simply have a `mysql_select_db`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are on the same database host (localhost) you can just get them in one query. This method uses a subquery which `UNION`s together the query from each database, then does an aggregate `SUM()` to add them together.

```
SELECT SUM(postcounts) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(postId) AS postcounts FROM mydb1.my_table
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT COUNT(postId) AS postcounts FROM mydb2.my_table
) allposts
```

The reason your `mysql_num_rows()` returns a count of 1 is because each of your queries only returns one row - the aggregate `COUNT(postIdD)`.  If you wanted to retrieve the actual count, you need to fetch the row.

Supposing the query above was stored in `$result`, the value you need is aliased as `total`:

```
if ($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $row['total'];
}
```

The whole thing looks like:

```
$db1 = mysql_connect($connection,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database1, $db1);
$query = "    
    SELECT SUM(postcounts) AS total
    FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(postId) AS postcounts FROM mydb1.my_table
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT COUNT(postId) AS postcounts FROM mydb2.my_table
    ) allposts ";

$result = mysql_query($query, $db1);

// Fetch the resultant row
if ($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $row['total'];
}
```

Comment: Beautiful!  It works perfectly!  Thanks so much.. and for educating me along the way.  My MySQL and PHP skills are both minimal but I'm a good learner when I see a good example, as you provided.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Andi Happy to help. Complete and informative answers are really important to me

Answer (score 0):

You're making 2 connections, but you're only printing the results from connection 2:

```
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);
print $total_rows;
```

Do something like:

```
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2 + $result1);
print $total_rows;
```

Comment: Hi Paul.  I guess I didn't explain it well.  I was saying that I haven't attempted the adding yet. I understand that I would do something like you did above.  I'm just saying that the result I'm trying to pull from only 1 database isn't working, using the code I have.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It looks like you're setting the variable `$sel2`, but you're not doing anything with it. PHP doesn't know what you're trying to select.